# how to make the first letter of the word BOLD

Tags: android, html, button

I have a button on my UI which says, "Active Engagement" and "Active Non-Engagement", how can i do it such that the first letter of the word will be BOLD

Eg: **A**ctive **E**ngagement, **A**ctive **N**on-Engagement

This is the code for my button:

```
<Button
                        android:id="@+id/btnAE"
                        android:layout_width="200dp"
                        android:layout_height="79dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/button_selector"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:text="Active\n Engagement"
                        android:textColor="#ffffffff"
                        android:textSize="17dp"
                        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btnPE"
                        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btnPNE" />


<Button
                        android:id="@+id/btnANE"
                        android:layout_width="200dp"
                        android:layout_height="79dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/button_selector"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:text="Active Non\nEngagement"
                        android:textColor="#ffffffff"
                        android:textSize="17dp"
                        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btnPNE"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
String button_title = "<B>A</B>ctive"; //You can use html tag to format your string

Button my_button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.my_button);    
my_button.setText(Html.fromHtml(button_title));
```

Comment: May i know where would you input this? Because I have 2 files (.java and .xml). It only applies to the .xml file, as shown in my question. I tried to apply this piece of code in .java file but it doesn't seem to work..

Answer (score 0):

In Android use this,

Say you have a TextView called etx. You would then use the following code:

```
final SpannableStringBuilder sb = new SpannableStringBuilder("HELLOO");

final StyleSpan bss = new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD); // Span to make text bold
final StyleSpan iss = new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.ITALIC); //Span to make text italic
sb.setSpan(bss, 0, 4, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE); // make first 4 characters Bold 
sb.setSpan(iss, 4, 6, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE); // make last 2 characters Italic

etx.setText(sb);
```